# Virtual consoles, shells and Xorg - how they interact?

Tags: linux, console, x11, xorg

Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) says:

> usually the first six virtual consoles provide a text terminal with a login prompt to a Unix shell. The graphical X Window System starts in the seventh virtual console.

Does this mean that Xorg is just a GUI wraparound for terminal/console/shell commands? More precisely, does Xorg translate GUI commands (mouse clicks, e.g.) to shell commands, which are then passed on to kernel as system calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Xorg translate GUI commands (...) to shell commands?

Nope, not at all. It's just a little trick supported by the Linux kernel to hand off the keyboard & mouse to X11 and vice versa when switching back to a text console.

I don't know the details, it's probably hack-ish code to let it all happen. Basically, when you hit Alt-F7 (or whatever console X is running on) the kernel goes: "Oh yeah, there's this program called 'X' running here, go ahead and do your stuff". When switching back to text when you hit Ctrl-Alt-F1..6, X releases it hold on the graphics cards and calls back to the kernel: "Yo, you should switch back to console 1..6!"

Comment: Thanks, if I can ask to add a bit more context: how then Xorg interacts with kernel? Does it use the same system calls, which are available to shells?

Comment: Strictly speaking all system calls are available to all programs, shells and X11 alike. X is just a program, a complicated one that drives graphics cards on one side and takes graphics commands (e.g. paint lines and boxes) on the other. The interaction is through an ioctl() call, here is a bit more information: [How vt switching works](https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/how-vt-switching-works/)